Считаются ли серийным голосованием три минуса за три ответа разных авторов на один и тот же вопрос?
Сегодня снова столкнулся с анонимным бессловесным минусатором ответа на не слишком сложный вопрос Как переписать регулярное выражение, что с квадратными скобками удаляло запятые в строке.
Вроде бы дело житейское, но оказалось, что аналогичными минусами без комментариев были вознаграждены и два других ответа:

@pyduti привёл решения для Java и JavaScript
@ksa привёл работающий пример для JavaScript

То есть, некий "учитель" просто продемонстрировал своё "фэ" трём разным людям -- типа нефиг пытаться "майнить репу" на халяве.
Вопрос собственно в следующем — считается ли такое "антиголосование" серийным?

Это безусловно злит, но с этим ничего не сделать. К счастью. таких "учителей" не так много. В метке [tag:java] это скорее всего одна и та же персона делает. Вариант один – незаслуженно заминусованное  —заплюсоовать.

@Зонтик, не к счастью, а к сожалелнию... Вангую, что минусатор таким образом выражает свое негодование использованием регэкспов в таком контексте (в принципе, любых регэкспов в контексте программной обработки текста, не с целью поиска и показа в интерактиве). Кстати, сам вопрос тоже заминусован

@avp Автор этого топика написал в том ответе, что регулярки не нужны.  Но всё равно получил минус. К тому же, такие случаи не единичны, сам такое часто замечал. Пример: ответы на этот вопрос. Или на этот

Насколько я в курсе, серийное голосование — это при голосах, отданных какому-то одному участнику за короткий период времени. Условно: прошелся по ответам одного автора и влепил везде минус — серийное голосование. А если влепил столько же минусов, но разным авторам, то уже не серийное.
Некоторая дополнительная информация в справке.
